# ASSUME directive using masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I have been attempting to write assembly code with using ASSUME but keep on getting errors that I have not been able to find out their causes. Here are a couple of examples:
Example 1

```
.286
.model medium, c
pproc typedef ptr proc
.data
dummy db ?
.code
assume bx:ptr pproc
call [bx]
end
```

no error occurs when it is assembled.

If I change the .286 to a .386 then I get the following error:
`Error A2158: type is wrong size for register`.
This error occurs for the line:
`Assume bx:ptr proc`

Why does it occur? What needs to be changed in the ASSUME to correct the error?

Note: I noticed that pproc is defined by the assembler as a FAR pointer. WHY?

---

example 2:

```
.286
.model medium
.data
dummy db ?
.code
assume bx:near ptr 
call [bx]
call near ptr [bx[
end
```

Now if I just change the .286 to a .386 I get the following assembler error on:
`assume bx:near ptr`
`A2158: Type is wrong size for register`

Why do I get this error? This is a near segment.  Notice the instruction that does the same thing is without Assume.

---

example 3

```
.286
.model medium, c
.data
dummy db ?
.code
assume bx:ptr byte
mov [bx],12h
mov byte ptr [bx],12h
end
```

Now if I just change the .286 to a .386 I get the following errors when
attempt to assemble it

for line:  `assume bx:ptr byte` I get the error
`A2158: Type is wrong size for register`
Why does it occur? What needs to be changed in the ASSUME to correct the error?

for line:  `mov [bx],12h`
the following error occurs: `error 2070 :invalid instruction operands.`

Why do I get this error? Is this a bug? This should work, I am trying
to store `12h` into `[bx]`. Notice the instruction that does the same thing is without Assume.

Comment: `mov [bx],12h`  is an ambiguous operand-size.  The assembler doesn't know if you want a byte, word, or dword operand-size for that store.  (The error message is unfortunately terrible.  Use `mov word ptr  [bx], 12h` if that's what you want, or byte ptr.

Comment: For `assume`, .386 implies 32-bit pointers, and BX is still a 16-bit register.  It might also imply a flat memory model, IDK.

Comment: The mov [bx],12h instruction has a ASSUME instruction above it that specifies a byte size.I What I am asking about is why the ASSUME gives me a error message?

Comment: Did you notice that the instruction with the ASSUMe above them gave a error message .Yet the same instruction without a ASSUME did not.What has to be changed in the ASSUME to get rid of the error message?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question when that line did/didn't give an error.  Or even that it was affected by changing other lines.  I don't know MASM (mostly NASM and GAS), I didn't know `assume` could do anything beyond telling the assembler what segment base you were going to have DS or ES set to.  Seems like better style IMO to make the size explicit where you use the register, even if there is syntax that exists to imply it from some other line.  But anyway, are you sure it's `ptr byte` instead of `byte ptr`?

Comment: @PeterCordes : The `.386` doesn't imply a flat model. You can use `.386` with real mode models and it will allow you to generate 386 instructions in real mode.

Comment: As well the OP is correct. Assume directives use `ptr xxxx` and not `xxxx ptr` when associating types with registers.

Comment: I've added an important section to my answer that may shed light on your issue with NEAR and FAR when it is related to JMP/CALL in an indirect memory reference.

Answer (score 3):

The [MASM 6.1 documentation](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf) is a good resource for writing real-mode segmented code (non-FLAT models). Page 43-47 have good info on ASSUME, and segment word sizes. What you are encountering is a side effect of a rather subtle way in which ASSUME will operate depending on *where* you place the `.386` directive relative to the `.MODEL` directive. This subtle behaviour is documented in the section *Setting Segment Word Sizes (80386/486 Only)*:

> **Setting Segment Word Sizes (80386/486 Only)**
>
> The use type in the SEGMENT directive specifies the segment word size
>   on the 80386/486 processors. Segment word size determines the default
>   operand and address size of all items in a segment. The size attribute
>   can be USE16, USE32, or FLAT. **If you specify the .386 or .486
>   directive before the .MODEL directive, USE32 is the default. This
>   attribute specifies that items in the segment are addressed with a
>   32-bit offset rather than a 16-bit offset. If .MODEL precedes the .386
>   or .486 directive, USE16 is the default.** To make USE32 the default,
>   put .386 or .486 before .MODEL. You can override the USE32 default
>   with the USE16 attribute, or vice versa.

What you need to be careful about is where you place `.386`. You have placed it before `.model` thus the assembler is assuming that all the sections are `USE32` by default. You appear to be writing code that will run in 16-bit real-mode (possibly using 386 instructions and registers) so I believe you will want to ensure `USE16` is the default when using the `.code` and `.data` directives. To get the behaviour you want I think you might wish to consider changing:

```
.386
.model medium, c
```

To:

```
.model medium, c
.386
```

And observe what happens.

---

This is a second issue which I believe you are experiencing. MASM 5.1 had this [supplemental information](http://bytepointer.com/masm/ml51_readme.htm) added to it that may shed light on your issue with `FAR PTR` and `NEAR PTR`. It reads as follows:

> ### The PTR Operator
>
> The PTR operator can be used to specify the size of a **register indirect operand for a CALL or JMP instruction**. However, **the
>   size cannot be specified with NEAR or FAR Use WORD or DWORD instead.
>   (In 80386 32-bit segments, use DWORD or FWORD.)** Examples are shown
>   below:
>
> ```
>       ; 8086, 80826, or 80386 16-bit mode
>
>       jmp  WORD PTR [bx]        ; Legal near jump
>       call NEAR PTR [bx]        ; Illegal near call
>       call DWORD PTR [bx]       ; Legal far call
>       jmp  FAR PTR [bx]         ; Illegal far jump
>
>       ; 80386 32-bit mode only
>
>       jmp  DWORD PTR [bx]       ; Legal near jump
>       call NEAR PTR [bx]        ; Illegal near call
>       call FWORD PTR [bx]       ; Legal far call
>       jmp  FAR PTR [bx]         ; Illegal far jump
> ```
>
> **This limitation only applies to register indirect operands. NEAR or
>   FAR can be applied to operands associated with labels.** Examples are
>   shown below:
>
> ```
>       jmp  NEAR PTR pointer[bx] ; Legal
>       call FAR PTR location     ; Legal
> ```

In a `USE32` section if you want to do an indirect FAR JMP/CALL use:

```
pproc typedef ptr fword
```

If you want to do a near indirect call in a `USE32` section do:

```
pproc typedef ptr dword
```

In a `USE16` section if you want to do an indirect FAR JMP/CALL use:

```
pproc typedef ptr dword
```

If you want to do a near indirect call in a `USE16` section do:

```
pproc typedef ptr word
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. So why does ASSUME care if it is use16 or use32? It should only care if the register size being used is <= specified size to be used? The reason I say that is if you specify the size to use in the instruction it does not care if the segment is use16 or use32. This just makes it harder to write the code.

Comment: @StillLearning Do you intend to mix 32-bit and 16-bit instructions?For instance why do you want to use `.386` rather than `.286`? You may have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) . What are you trying to do by using `.386`.. What do you wish to achieve with it?

Comment: To have the code examples you gave:for the PTR operator work insert  a  " ASSUME BX:Word" before all of them and then they are all valid..

Comment: @StillLearning : you have a ways to go to understand. The generated code for indirect calls (the bytes actually emitted) differ between use32 and use16. You;ve been so focused on getting the assembler to compile without an error but have looked past the generated opcodes which are different depending on what mode (16 or 32-bit code) the section is in. I have a suspicion this is some kind of [X-Y problem] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem_ here which prompted me to ask why you are using .386 directive.

Answer (score 2):

In all the examples you are telling MASM to consider `bx` a pointer to something<sup>1</sup> (first a procedure, than anything near, than a byte) and in all cases these pointers are near (which is implicit unless otherwise declared).

If you specify `.286` MASM creates a default data segment that is assumed to be addressable by 16-bit, similar for the default code segment (default operand/address size is 16-bit).
If you use `.386` the 32-bit versions are created.

Near pointers to a 16-bit data segment are 16-bit and near pointers to a 32-bit data segments are 32-bit.
The register `bx` is always 16-bit instead.
So `.386` with `ASSUME BX: PTR <SOMETHING>` cannot work.

---

<sup>1</sup> 
I assume this is useful for some ugly high-level blending, like warning you if you load/store a different type or allowing you to access struct members.
`ASSUME` is useful/essential with segment registers in a segment environment, the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/assume?view=vs-2019) seems disastrously incomplete in completely glossing over it.

Comment: Then why can I create the same instruction by using explicit size (word ptr) in a instruction and it does work but does not work in a ASSUME instruction? Notice the error ONLY happens when using ASSUME.

Comment: In the examples that I gave, in my opinion, those errors should not exist. The reason is that the same instruction can be created by using explicit size PTR specifiers within the instruction.

Comment: @StillLearning: This answer is saying that `.386` only lets you use `assume` with 32-bit pointer registers, like EBX or EAX.  It's not the width of the *data* that's the problem, it's the width of the *pointer*.  `mov byte ptr [bx], 12h` is a valid encodeable x86 instruction even in 32-bit mode, so MASM still lets you write it explicitly, but it's not going to *help* you write it because 16-bit addressing modes are probably a mistake for 32-bit code.  (At least that reasoning explains MASM's behaviour here.)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: your edit pasted some text instead of an actual URL for the manual.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I reverted the change since I cover that URL in my answer.

Comment: @StillLearning `ASSUME` tells MASM what data type you are making a register hold. If, for example, you tell itthat `bx` holds a pointer to a byte, then MASM won't let you access a word and it will let you not specify the operand size of the move even though such an instruction is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Michael:

Here is an example of code that creates 16-bit code:

```
.Model small,c ;since cpu instruction is after .Model it causes USE16 to be used
.286
.code
assume bx:word
call bx
end
```

Since use16 is in effect this creates a 16-bit segment and the .286 tells it to use 16-bit instructions. When the above code is assembled it creates the opcodes FF D3 for the Call bx instruction. The instructions "call NEAR PTR bx" or "call NEAR16 PTR bx" also create the same op codes.

Here is another example of code that creates 32-bit code:

```
.Model small,c ;since cpu instruction is after .Model it causes USE16 to be used
.386
.code
assume ebx:dword
call ebx
end
```

Since use16 is in effect this creates a 16-bit segment and the .386 tells it to use 32-bit instructions. When the above code is assembled it creates the opcodes 66 FF D3 for the Call ebx instruction. The instructions "call NEAR PTR ebx" or "call NEAR32 PTR ebx" or "call FAR16 ptr ebx" also create the same op codes. The assembler recognizes that 386 instructions are being used in a 16-bit segment this causes the assembler to insert before
each 386 instruction a 66 in hex. Notice that both op code for 16-bit and 32-bit are the same the only difference is the prefix op code being there. If a 32-bit segment was created and a 16-bit instruction is being used then the same 66 in hex prefix code is put before the 16-bit op codes. Notice that the prefix byte being there or not there is the only difference. The prefix op code (66) is only put there when the segment use size (use16 or use32) does not match the cpu instruction size (16-bit or 32-bit). The rules should be the same for ASSUME using 16-bit or 32-bit registers but they are not in MASM.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the purpose of MASM Assume Directive](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=16617;prev_next=next) is an excellent summary of the usage of the ASSUME directive. Back in the olden days, it was common as well to see it used to specify a list of segment registers. That usage is pretty much obsolete on modern processors.

Comment: Thanks David for the link but it did not answer any of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing I have discovered the "rules" for a ASSUME statement with the following format: ASUME register: PTR size

Allowed Settings for "ASSUME reg: PTR {Size}

```
Cases where cpu instruction is BEFORE .MODEL or no cpu instruction before .MODEL:

                             |user supplied |  condition
                             |   values     |
                             |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is  |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
before tiny,small or medium  |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR|
.MODEL or no cpu instruction 
before tiny,small or medium
.MODEL. Causes internal use16. 

                             |user supplied |  condition
                             |   values     |
                             |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is  |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
before compact,large,or huge |16-bit | WORD |can only use WORD, no PTR     |
.MODEL or no cpu instruction 
before compact,large or huge
.MODEL. Causes internal use16. 

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR       |
before tiny,small or medium    |16-bit | WORD |can only use WORD, no PTR       |
.MODEL. Causes internal use32. |32-bit |DWORD |if <DWORD or >DWORD requires PTR|

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR       |
before compact,large,or huge   |16-bit | WORD |can only use WORD, no PTR       |
.MODEL. Causes internal use32. |32-bit |DWORD |if <DWORD or >DWORD requires PTR|

Cases where cpu instruction is AFTER .MODEL 

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is    |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
after tiny,small or medium     |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR|
.MODEL. Causes internal use16. 

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is    |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
after compact,large,or huge    |16-bit | WORD |can only use WORD, no PTR     |
.MODEL. Causes internal use16.

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
after tiny,small or medium     |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR|
.MODEL. Causes internal use16. |32-bit |DWORD |can only use DWORD, no PTR    |

                               |user supplied |  condition  
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR       |
after compact,large,or huge    |16-bit | WORD |can only use WORD, no PTR       |
.MODEL. Causes internal use16. |32-bit |DWORD |if <DWORD or >DWORD requires PTR|

THIS IS THE WAY IT SHOULD BE:

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is    |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
before any .MODEL instruction  |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR|
or no cpu instruction before
.MODEL. Causes internal use16.

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR       |
before any .MODEL instruction. |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR  |
Causes internal use32.         |32-bit |DWORD |if <DWORD or >DWORD requires PTR|


                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.286 instruction or less is    |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR     |
after any .MODEL instruction   |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR|
Causes internal use16.

                               |user supplied |  condition
                               |   values     |
                               |  reg  | size |
.386 instruction or greater is |8-bit  | BYTE |can only use BYTE, no PTR       |
after any .MODEL instruction.  |16-bit | WORD |if <WORD or >WORD requires PTR  |
Causes internal use16.         |32-bit |DWORD |if <DWORD or >DWORD requires PTR|
```